# How many view controllers would I use in this app setup?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I am very new to iOS programming and iOS code design, and I am working on developing a simple iPhone application. The basic layout of my application is as follows:

[image: UI Mockup]

In the first page, the user is presented with a list of categories. Upon clicking on a category, several options with drop down. Upon clicking on an option, the application will transition to a page where the user will input a number of values and be presented with an output. How many view controllers would I need for this application? Based on the little experience I have, I was thinking of using a view controller for the main page and then one for each option, but is this necessary? Is there a way I could use less view controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how complicated and different each option is, you may be able to use one view controller for all options.

So..

1. Main view controller- Shows a list of categories, where options could show underneath when tapped
2. Option view controller- Shows input boxes with labels and an output box.  You may show/hide different inputs based on how many you need and you can change the label text accordingly.

This would give your app the smallest UI with the most flexibility, in case you added more options.

Of course design is very subjective and depends on the deeper details of the project, but based on your description, I would implement it with 2 view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

If the screen where you input the values can be generalised, then you will have only 2 view controllers.

But in the implementation of the first one, you will have to implement function:

```
func prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

to pass the data about the selected item. And the the second view controller should adjust its fields accordingly.